# Assigning values to names in list

Tags: python, numpy

```
def network(x):
    A = np.array(x)
    i = A[:,0]
    j = A[:,1]

    mat = np.zeros((5,5))

    for k in range(len(connections)):
        connections[n] = k[n].append(0 ,5)

    for k in range(1,5):
       mat[i[k],j[k]] = 1
    return mat
```

Please answer, it should print a matrix with 0s and 1s.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean "assign values 0-5 to the names in the list"? like anna=0, bob=1, ...? Then you're trying to make a graph from these based on the adjacent list?

Comment: `k[n]` makes no sense. `k` is an index into `connections`, not a list that can be indexed.

Comment: What is `n` supposed to be?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "how to assign values 0-5 to the names in the list" What does this mean? I can't understand your description. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, and show us a *complete* example - including a *call* to the function with exact, hard-coded input; show us what happens when you run the code; show us exactly what should happen instead; and explain how that is different.

Comment: anna should be 0, bob = 1 and so on

Comment: I want it to print a matrix so that the numbers affiliated with a person, correlate to a point in the matrix and that the point is equal to 1

Comment: "anna should be 0, bob = 1" *What is the rule that tells you this?* If I argue that instead anna should be 1 and bob should be 0, why am I wrong? Also, *what does this actually mean*? Do you want your program to have a variable named `anna` with a value of `0`? Or just what? Again - this will be much easier if you just *show exact, complete desired program output*, from a *complete program* that *other people can run, by copying and pasting without modification*.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please provide as much information as you can with your question:

- Runnable code (yours isn't)
- Expected result
- Actual result

Name your variables more descriptively, so the reader can infer what it's supposed to contain and use the documentation, you can't index on the items provided from the [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function.

Anyway, here's your function

```py
import numpy as np

connections = [
    ("anna", "bob"),
    ("anna", "bill"),
    ("ian", "anna"),
    ("tim", "bob"),
    ("bill", "tim"),
    ("ian", "tim"),
    ("bill", "bob"),
    ("ian", "bob"),
    ("ian", "bill"),
    ("dawn", "ian"),
    ("kate", "ian"),
]


def network_to_matrix(conn_list):

    num_provider = iter(range(len(conn_list) * 2))
    name_map = {
        name: next(num_provider)
        for name in {name for pair in conn_list for name in pair}
    }

    # keep this somewhere
    print(name_map)

    conn_mat = np.zeros(2 * (len(name_map),))
    for start, end in conn_list:
        start_index, end_index = name_map[start], name_map[end]
        conn_mat[start_index, end_index] = 1
        conn_mat[end_index, start_index] = 1

    return conn_mat


matrix = network_to_matrix(connections)
print(matrix)
```